# В чём разница терминальных операций в Java Stream API: count() и collect(Collectors.counting())?

Tags: java, потоки-данных, java-stream

`count()`
и

```
collect(Collectors.counting())
```

Не дублирующий ли это функционал?
Или есть какая-то разница, тогда что предпочтительнее использовать?

Я пока не нашёл ситуаций, где второй не мог бы заменить первый.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вместо `.collect(Collectors.counting())` лучше использовать `.count()`, т.к. это более читаемо и по-сути делает то же самое.

Но `Collectors.counting()` может пригодиться для других целей, например его можно использовать в коллекторах вроде `Collectors.groupingBy`, `Collectors.collectingAndThen` и т.д.

**Пример**

Есть класс продукта:

```
public class Product {
    private final String name;               // имя продукта
    private final String manufacturerName;   // имя производителя

    // далле конструкоры, геттеры и т.д.
    //...
}
```

и список продуктов:

```
List<Product> products = Arrays.asList(
                new Product("product1", "manufacturer1"),
                new Product("product2", "manufacturer2"),
                new Product("product3", "manufacturer1")
        );
```

Допустим, что нужно получить `Map`, в котором ключ - это имя производителя, а значение - количество произведенных продуктов.
Сделать это можно с использованием `Collectors.counting` (*будет выглядеть менее громоздко, если использовать статические импорты*):

```
products
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Product::getManufacturerName, Collectors.counting()))
```

Результат выполнения: `{manufacturer1=2, manufacturer2=1}`

Answer (score 1):

Терминальный метод `count()` обладает одной интересной собенностью - если в цепочке промежуточных операций не будет операций изменения количества данных источника (например `filter()`), то эти промежуточные операции не будут выполняться. По сути компилятор производит оптимизацию для ускорения получения результата. Например:

```
list.stream().map(Object::toString).peek(System.out::println).count();
```

ничего не выведет на консоль, в то время как `collect(Collectors.counting())` обеспечит стандартное выполнение всех методов в цепочке.